# Prove that, for $f(x), g(x)$ convex, $\alpha_f f(x) + \alpha_g g(x)$ is also convex for $x ∈ S \subset \mathbb R^n$ where $\alpha_f, \alpha_g\ge0$.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I am starting to get some basic knowledge on convex sets and convex functions. I am a bit struck at this question:

If $f(x),g(x)$ are convex, then $\alpha_f f(x) + \alpha_g g(x)$ is also convex for $x \in S \subset \mathbb R^n$ where $\alpha_f, \alpha_g > 0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is a fairly straight forward application of the inequality definition of convex functions. Did you try to show the defining inequality holds for $\alpha_f f(x) + \alpha_g g(x)$? If so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: You mean to say i apply jensens inequality ??

Right now i am just aware of convex function definition

Comment: Honestly I didn't understand your question. First, are $ag$ and $af$ constant? If yes, the notation is poorly selected. Then, what is $S$?

Comment: yes they are scalar constants like we write a linear equation Y=5x
S is a set of real Numbers. In Some books it is R2 Space

Comment: Yes, Jensen's inequality. I keep forgetting that inequality has a name. What definition do you use? The one with epigraphs?

Comment: yes we are required to use epigraphs. That was the hint instructor gave

Comment: I would suggest that you start by proving that positive real multiples of convex functions are convex (it shouldn't be too hard to prove using epigraphs). Then, prove that the sum of two convex functions is convex. Together, these imply the more daunting-looking task you've been assigned.